# Turn on the flash on an android phone using App Inventor 2

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, app-inventor

I am getting to know how to build android apps by starting using App Inventor 2, as a start. I would like to turn on the flash on an android phone (I dont want the camera display, just flash). I found out how to do this by code, however, in App Inventor I need to use Activity starter to do this.

There are three parameters to fill here:
Action, ActivityClass and ActivityPackage.

A simple example is launching the camera on android, which will look like this:

> Action: android.intent.action.MAIN
>
> ActivityPackage: com.google.android.camera
>
> ActivityClass: com.android.camera.Camera

However, when it comes to the flash, it looks more complicated for me. From the following link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html, I understand that I have to set parameters. One of these belong to the flash (FLASH_MODE_TORCH is the one I need I believe). Remember that I don't want a camera preview, in that case, what action will turn on the flash continuously (since the torch is not a class itself)?

Comment: as far as I know, unfortunately this is not possible with App Inventor and the activity starter. You might find [this example app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_mletsch80.AppInvActivityStarter) useful to see, what *is* possible...